# Вызов функции из родительского модуля в рамках телеграм бота

Tags: python, telebot

parent.py

```
from child import child_function

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'], )
def parent_function(message)
    menu = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    menu.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="text", 
    callback_data ='cb_data'))

    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='text', 
    reply_markup=menu)

bot.register_callback_query_handler(child_function, func=lambda call: call.data == 'cb_data', pass_bot=True)
```

child.py

```
   def child_function(call, bot)
        menu = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        menu.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="text", 
        callback_data ='cb_data_child'))
    
        msg = bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, text='text', 
        reply_markup=menu)
```

если в дочернем модуле попытаться выбрать функцию из родительского `from parent import parent_function` , то программа вылетает с ошибкой
`ImportError: cannot import name 'parent_funсtion' from 'parent' )`

1. как вызвать функцию parent_funсtion родительского модуля из дочернего?
2. как передать в нее параметр message вместо call и bot?

Comment: А у вас опечатка в сообщении ошибки (cannot import name 'parent_fun**d**tion' from 'parent') - это случайность при вводе ошибки сюда, или в коде тоже опечатка?

Comment: опечатка при вводе ошибки (в моем скрипте функция по-другому называется)